# Active question from a user, but without activity?

Tags: support, questions, recent-activity

Someone know if it's a bug, I seen that;

[image]

But When I click to see the change, I see nothing, like show there;

[image]

If it was a revoked edit, why it still show as active in my list ?

Question link; [megacli lost virtual disk raid configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/665106/megacli-lost-virtual-disk-raid-configuration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user posted an answer and then self-deleted it.

The post would still have been active today if a moderator had deleted the answer, as well.

When you reach 10,000 reputation, you will be able to see deleted questions and answers.